# Flask's send_file() function keeps changing directories while looking for the file

Tags: python, flask

There are 2 functions or views located in the same file `version.py`, one for upload the other for downloading that file. The issue is that the send_file function keeps changing directories while opening the file.
Code 1:
File Upload function:

```
                binfile = form.binfile.data
                filename = secure_filename("arduino.bin")
#without the app folder
                binfile.save(os.path.join(
                    app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'], 
                    device_names.farm_id, 
                    device_names.mqtt_id, 
                    filename))
                flash('File Uploaded', 'success')
```

File Download Function:

```
file_path = os.path.join(
                    app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'], 
                    farm_id, 
                    device_id, 
                    'arduino.bin')
                print(file_path)
                response = make_response(send_file(
                    file_path, 
                    mimetype='application/octet-stream',
                    as_attachment=True
                    ))
                response.headers['x-MD5'] = md5(file_path)
                print(response.headers)
                return response, 200
```

Here the file gets uploaded to the project root folder.
When I send a request for this file, I get this error:

> [Errno 2] No such file or directory:
>   ‘/home/maxwell/Desktop/python/aquaponics-monitor/app/firmware-manager/FARM0/node2/arduino.bin’

When I manually move the file to the 'app' folder I get no errors and a 200 response code while requesting. So I assume that the function is looking for the file inside the 'app' folder. I changed the upload location by adding 'app' to the path while uploading.

Code 2:
File Upload Function:

```
                binfile = form.binfile.data
                filename = secure_filename("arduino.bin")
#app folder included
                binfile.save(os.path.join(
                    'app',
                    app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'], 
                    device_names.farm_id, 
                    device_names.mqtt_id, 
                    filename))
                flash('File Uploaded', 'success')
```

The file download function is the same as code 1. For this code I get this error:

> [Errno 2] No such file or directory:
>   ‘firmware-manager/FARM0/node2/arduino.bin’

The file download function now looks in the project root folder. I manually moved the file to the root folder this time and I again get a status code 200 and no errors when I send a request for it. 
The only code change I made in the entire application is adding 'app' to the path in the File Upload function. Why is this happening?